# Silverlight WebBrowser control. Does it provide the same functionality across Windows and Mac?

Tags: silverlight, cross-platform, webbrowser-control

I am new to Silverlight, so my question may sound silly. But does WebBrowser control in Silverlight allow to do the same things no matter what operating system uses an end-users of an application?

I'm thinking of implementing an application that will need to process user-supplied HTML and I will possibly use WebBrowser control to ease the parsing.

**EDIT**

My worries are inner interfaces like `IHTMLDocument2`, `IHTMLElementRender` etc that I will probably need to use. Not sure Silverlight will provide access to them, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be awfully close, but implementation details across platforms may differ slightly.  On Windows, the WebBrowser control uses WebOC (the rendering technology in IE), and on MacOS it uses WebKit (the rendering technology in Safari, among others).

So for example, if you use CSS that only works in WebKit, then the Windows WebBrowser control won't look how you expect.

Thus, I recommend keeping the HTML you show as something that works cross-browser already.  This is one of those places that Silverlight unfortunately doesn't make it any easier, it just delegates to the host OS.

Other than that, everything should be groovy.  Do you have particual features you're concerned might not work?  If so, I could look into whether they do work the same.

Comment: Austin, I'm not particularly worry about different rendering of HTML. I might even say that rendering as close to IE on Windows or Safari on Mac as possible is good. My worries are inner interfaces that I will probably need to use like `IHTMLDocument2`, `IHTMLElementRender` etc. Not sure Silverlight will give access to them, though.

Comment: Yeah, Silverlight  doesn't expose those interfaces, so the public API on the WebBrowser control (see MSDN, it's a pretty small API actually) is all you'll get, and it's consistent across platforms (or if it's not, that's a bug, not intentional).

Comment: Thank you, Austin! Probably, I will need to rethink my approach to the problem.

Comment: If you have specific requirements around what `IHTMLDocument2` or other interfaces provide, let me know.  WebBrowser does provide a lot via some simple interfaces (NavigateToString, and the ability to talk 2-way with JavaScript, can do a surprising amount but it is rather ugly...)

Comment: Austin, please take a look at my new more specific question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4780298/249690